# Cannot find Tamil phonetic and tamil99 input method in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, input-language, input-method, internationalization

I am unable to find and use tamil-99 or tamil phonetic typing even after installing tamil language support and ibus-m17n.

Installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ibus-gtk* ibus-m17n m17n-* tamil*
[sudo] password for vanangamudi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ibus-gtk' for glob 'ibus-gtk*'
Note, selecting 'ibus-gtk3' for glob 'ibus-gtk*'
Note, selecting 'm17n-lib-mimx' for glob 'm17n-*'
Note, selecting 'm17n-contrib' for glob 'm17n-*'
Note, selecting 'm17n-im-config' for glob 'm17n-*'
Note, selecting 'm17n-db' for glob 'm17n-*'
Note, selecting 'm17n-lib-bin' for glob 'm17n-*'
Note, selecting 'm17n-docs' for glob 'm17n-*'
Note, selecting 'tamil-gtk2im' for glob 'tamil*'
ibus-m17n is already the newest version (1.4.2-1).
m17n-db is already the newest version (1.8.0-3).
m17n-docs is already the newest version (1.6.2-2).
m17n-im-config is already the newest version (0.9.0-5).
m17n-lib-bin is already the newest version (1.8.0-2).
m17n-lib-mimx is already the newest version (1.8.0-2).
tamil-gtk2im is already the newest version (2.2-6).
ibus-gtk is already the newest version (1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1).
ibus-gtk3 is already the newest version (1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1).
ibus-gtk3 set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  emacs emacs-bin-common emacs-common emacs-el emacs-gtk xaw3dg
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
vanangamudi@karunthulai:~$
```

Comment: Log out and log in again.

Comment: I tried that and even after reboot it is not listing.

Comment: Click "Tamil". It should open a sub menu which includes the input methods you mentioned.

Comment: No, that is where it is not listing. I have installed all m17n and ibus packages plus tamil* packages too

Comment: That's strange. What if you navigate to the "Other" window?

Comment: Tamil is shown under 'Others'

Comment: Did you really install the `ibus-m17n` package successfully?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson added the installation log above

Comment: I read all of this http://tamillinux.sourceforge.net/venkat/tamil_inst.html and only understood about half of it but maybe you will have better luck.

Comment: @vanangamudi: I suspect that you are missing some trivial detail. If you open _Settings -> Region & Language_, click the + button for adding _Input Sources_, navigate to the _Other_ window, and type `tamil`, those input methods ought to be there. Please note that you may need to scroll a bit to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed all `m17n-* ibus-*` packages and it still was not working. The Tamil input method was shown in neither `ibus-setup` or [Region & Language] pane from Gnome settings.

The problem was the directory where the m17n files reside i.e `/usr/share/m17n/` was empty. my friend who is also on Ubuntu 20.04 took control of my machine and figured this out. we copied the files under `/usr/share/m17n` from his machine to mine and it works now.

Note: The Gnome [Region and Language] settings seems to work independently of `ibus-setup` config because

- even though the `ibus` was selected as the default input methods in [Language Support] dialog from Gnome
- and Tamil input-methods (phonetic, tamil99) were added via `ibus-setup`,

the input methods listed via both hotkey, button on the dock are the items from [Region and Language] settings.

Once I added the input methods using [Region and Language] settings pane I am now able to type in Tamil.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Tamil99 / Tamil typing using ibus-typing-booster ?

It remembers words typed, offers them and words from dictionary as suggestions like Android Gboard. It also learns word from text file uploaded. Tamil dictionary is not yet available. Any word file can be stored as txt file and uploaded for learning.

ibus-typing-booster is now available in Ubuntu repositories in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Install ibus-m17n and ibus-typing-booster with dependencies.

In Settings > Region & Languages > Manage installed languages > language support >

install/remove language> select desired languages > apply

select ibus from the dropdown menu under Keyboard Input Method System

In Region Language > Input Sources > add an input source > three vertical dots > search with keyword "other" --> select other --> add typing booster from the list

Select typing booster keyboard in input source --> settings/preferences --> add the required dictionaries and input methods

Unicode  symbol emoji slows, so avoid using it.

Some details about ibus-typing-booster ->
https://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-typing-booster/documentation.html